# Is there a better way to provide a helper methods to test a web application than using a single class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, inheritance

I'm designing UI Tests for a web application with Selenium in JUnit. I have a base test class with something like this from which I inherit my tests:

```
public class BaseTest {

    protected TestSteps test;

    protected Assertions assertion;

    // set everything up...

}
```

and the tests then only look like this:

```
public class TestX extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public testFeature1() {
        test.clickSomething().enterSomething(); // method chaining
        assertion.assertSomething();

        //...
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having: There are different modules in the web app, and `Assertions/TestSteps` methods that only apply to one module clutter the interface of the `Assertions/TestSteps` class for the other modules.

Thus I tried to split the Assertions/TestSteps up. 
The problem is, the method chaining returns instances of TestSteps. Of course, when I have `Module1TestSteps` with method `doSomethingSpecific()` then I would expect `test.clickSomething().doSomethingSpecific()` to work, but it does not, because `clickSomething()` would return a `TestSteps` instance, not a `Module1TestSteps` instance.

I "solved" this by making an `AbstractTestSteps<T extends AbstractTestSteps<T>` class (which contains all the base TestSteps methods) `protected abstract T getThis();`.

I then extend this class like this:

```
public class BaseTestSteps extends AbstractTestSteps<BaseTestSteps> {

    // Constructors

    protected BaseTestSteps getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    // that's it, the "base methods" are all inherited from AbstractTestSteps...

}
```

for the base TestSteps and

```
public class Module1TestSteps extends AbstractTestSteps<Module1TestSteps> {

    // same constructors...

    protected Module1TestSteps getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    public Module1TestSteps doSomeThingSpecific() {
        // do something

        return getThis();
    }

}
```

for my specialized `TestSteps`. It works for now, but I don't like it because of the following reasons:

- All the general methods are in the `AbstractTestSteps` class, but they are used through an instance of `BaseTestSteps`
- What if I have a submodule of `Module1`? I can't inherit from `Module1TestSteps`, only from AbstractTestSteps.
- I think it's not trivial to understand the relation of these classes when one of my colleagues tries to add a new `TestSteps` class.

How can this be made better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Page Object pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects). That is, create an API for each page so that your tests describe navigating and interacting with pages in a way that describes the user's experience.

It has a few benefits that address your concerns:

- It uses composition, not inheritance
- It is easy to understand and explain to people maintaining the tests because the tests read like a description of somebody using the application